# Stopping an NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperationQueue that handles importing data from a web server on a loop. It accomplishes this with the following design.

1. NSURLConnect is wrapped in an NSOperation and added to the Queue
2. On successful completion of the download (using a block), the data from the request is wrapped in another NSOperation that adds the relevant data to Core Data. This operation is added to the queue.
3. On successful completion (using another block), (and after a specified delay) I call the method that started it all and return to step 1. Thus, i make another server call x seconds later.

This works great. I'm able to get data from the server and handle everything on the background. And because these are just NSOperations I'm able to put everything in the background, and perform multiple requests at a time. This works really well.

The ONLY problem that I currently have is that I'm unable to successfully cancel the operations once they are going.

I've tried something like the following :

```
- (void)flushQueue
{
    self.isFlushingQueue = YES;
    [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
    [self.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    self.isFlushingQueue = NO;
    NSLog(@"successfully flushed Queue");

}
```

where self.isFlushingQueue is a BOOL that I use to check before adding any new operations to the queue. This seems like it should work, but in fact it does not. Any ideas on stopping my Frankenstein creation?

**Edit (Solved problem, but from a different perspective)**

I'm still baffled about why exactly I was unable to cancel these operations (i'd be happy to keep trying possible solutions), but I had a moment of insight on how to solve this problem in a slightly different way. Instead of dealing at all with canceling operations, and waiting til queue is finished, I decided to just have a data structure (NSMutableDictionary) that had a list of all active connections. Something like this :

```
self.activeConnections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                          @"UpdateContacts": @YES,
                          @"UpdateGroups" : @YES}];
```

And then before I add any operation to the queue, I simply ask if that particular call is On or Off. I've tested this, and I successfully have finite control over each individual server request that I want to be looping. To turn everything off I can just set all connections to @NO.

There are a couple downsides to this solution (Have to manually manage an additional data structure, and every operation has to start again to see if it's on or off before it terminates).

**Edit -- In pursuit of a more accurate solution**

I stripped out all code that isn't relevant (notice there is no error handling). I posted two methods. The first is an example of how the request NSOperation is created, and the second is the convenience method for generating the completion block.

Note the completion block generator is called by dozens of different requests similar to the first method.

```
- (void)updateContactsWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options
{
    //Hard coded for ease of understanding
    NSString *contactsURL = @"api/url";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"sortBy" : @"LastName"};

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self createRequestUsingURLString:contactsURL andParameters:params];

    ConnectionCompleteBlock processBlock = [self blockForImportingDataToEntity:@"Contact"
                                                                 usingSelector:@selector(updateContactsWithOptions:)
                                                                   withOptions:options andParsingSelector:@selector(requestUsesRowsFromData:)];

    BBYConnectionOperation *op = [[BBYConnectionOperation alloc] initWithURLRequest:request
                                                                        andDelegate:self
                                                                 andCompletionBlock:processBlock];

    //This used to check using self.isFlushingQueue
    if ([[self.activeConnections objectForKey:@"UpdateContacts"] isEqualToNumber:@YES]){
        [self.operationQueue addOperation:op];
    }

}

- (ConnectionCompleteBlock) blockForImportingDataToEntity:(NSString*)entityName usingSelector:(SEL)loopSelector withOptions:(NSDictionary*)options andParsingSelector:(SEL)parseSelector
{
    return ^(BOOL success, NSData *connectionData, NSError *error){

        //Pull out variables from options
        BOOL doesLoop = [[options valueForKey:@"doesLoop"] boolValue];
        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[options valueForKey:@"interval"] integerValue];

        //Data processed before importing to core data
        NSData *dataToImport = [self performSelector:parseSelector withObject:connectionData];

        BBYImportToCoreDataOperation *importOperation = [[BBYImportToCoreDataOperation alloc] initWithData:dataToImport 
          andContext:self.managedObjectContext 
          andNameOfEntityToImport:entityName];

        [importOperation setCompletionBlock:^ (BOOL success, NSError *error){
             if(success){
                 NSLog(@"Import %@s was successful",entityName);
                 if(doesLoop == YES){
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [self performSelector:loopSelector withObject:options afterDelay:timeInterval];
                     });
                 }
             }
         }];

        [self.operationQueue addOperation:importOperation];

    };
}
```

Comment: Your initial approach should work, but to tell why your cancellation doesn’t work I would have to see more code (how does your download `NSOperation` work and how are you adding your other operations?). Your final solution also could be problematic if you are accessing your mutable dictionary from multiple threads.

Comment: I'll post some additional code. I don't want any issues with the mutable dictionary on different threads. I'm hopeful that I wouldn't have any issues with the thread safety of the NSMutableDictionary. I can set the values of the dictionary on the main thread, and each connection is created on the main thread before being added to the queue to operate in the background, but admittedly I'm not entirely sure of myself as I'm relatively knew to multi threaded coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancellation of an NSOperation is just a request, a flag that is set in `NSOperation`.  It's up to your `NSOperation` subclass to actually action that request and cancel it's work.  You then need to ensure you have set the correct flags for `isExecuting` and `isFinished` etc.  You will also need to do this in a KVO compliant manner.  Only once these flags are set is the operation finished.

There is an example in the documentation [Concurrency Programming Guide -> Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8).  Although I understand that this example may not correctly account for all multi-threaded edge cases.  Another more complex example is provided in the sample code `LinkedImageFetcher` : `QRunLoopOperation`

If you think you are responding to the cancellation request correctly then you really need to post your NSOperation subclass code to examine the problem any further.

Comment: Perhaps you can clear up a bit of confusion I have on this subject. It's my understanding that you only need to override these methods and handle the flags if you are specifically declaring your NSOperation subclass as a "concurrent" operation. What are the benefits of making this distinction? Doesn't the Queue handle putting the operations on different threads? Finally, in regards to the question at hand. I'm quite certain my lack of implementing these features is the reason why my flush method wasn't working. Assuming, I implement these correctly my original flush method is valid and good?

Comment: I assumed that you were using `NSURLConnection` asynchronously. If so this would make your `NSOperation` concurrent.  If you have an inherently concurrent operation but aren't following the guidelines for managing it, then this could be the root of your problem.  Alternatively you may be using `sendSynchronousRequest` in which case I don't know what the cause of the problem is, but I'm not sure this is the best way to use NSURLConnection although it may be fine in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using your own flag for when it is ok to add more operations, you could try the

`- (void)setSuspended:(BOOL)suspend`

method on `NSOperationQueue`? And before adding a new operation, check if the queue is suspended with `isSuspended`?

Comment: I made these changes. Anywhere I add an operation i checked to see if suspended. And now my flushQueue looks like this :       [self.operationQueue setSuspended:YES];  
    [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];  
    [self.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];  
    [self.operationQueue setSuspended:NO];   
but unfortunately this has the same result.

Comment: Ok, it was perhaps a long shot. I see you found some kind of workaround at least =)